# Find Parent ListViewItem of button on Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a button as the last column of each ListViewItem.  When the button is pressed, I need to find the buttons (senders) parent list view item in the click event.

I have tried:

```
ListViewItem itemToCancel = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button).Parent as ListViewItem;

DiscoverableItem itemToCancel = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button).Parent as DiscoverableItem;
```

DiscoverableItem being the type that the listview is bound to.  I have tried all different combinations and each one returns null.

Thanks, 
Meisenman

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` to get an ancestor visual of some element. Of course it supports only the method `GetParent` but we can implement some recursive method or something similar to walk up the tree until the desired type of the parent is found:

```
public T GetAncestorOfType<T>(FrameworkElement child) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    if (parent != null && !(parent is T)) 
        return (T)GetAncestorOfType<T>((FrameworkElement)parent);
    return (T) parent;
}
```

Then you can use that method like this:

```
var itemToCancel = GetAncestorOfType<ListViewItem>(sender as Button);
//more check to be sure if it is not null 
//otherwise there is surely not any ListViewItem parent of the Button
if(itemToCancel != null){
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thank You!  Tested and works.  I have used this for finding the parent of a user control but did not realize that the listViewItem was not the direct parent of the button.  +1 & accepted