# WPF Listview button selecting item

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a button in a Listview column. When I press the button, the row does not select. I found one answer to the problem by using:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works to select the row, but when the row loses focus it doesn't stay selected, and I need to be able to select multiple rows.

I also tried this solution:

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
        </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void SelectCurrentItem(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem) sender;
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

This is closer to what I want, but now this affect selecting multiple items and now the user has to click twice on another item before it will select.

I also tried re-selecting the row in the click handler by using:

```
ListViewItem selectedRow = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as ListViewItem;
```

and

```
((sender as FrameworkElement).TemplatedParent as ListViewItem).IsSelected = true;
```

but these give me a null error. Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?

I have to use a Listview for other reasons, or I would just use a Datagrid, which works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a handler on the button click that reselects the row.

Comment: use `VisualTreeHelper` in order to find `ListViewItem` in visual tree

Comment: maybe set the Focusable property of the button ?

Comment: @Gosha That works great, thank you. Found a solution by adapting this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144400/find-parent-listviewitem-of-button-on-click-event