# How to run a loop while a button is pressed in listview item and update the item view?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, long-press

In my application I need to add to a counter while user presses the button the counter should be updated. I tried LongClick and this works nice:

```
productAddButton.LongClick += async (s,e) =>
            {
                while (productAddButton.Pressed)
                {
                    item.count++;
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                    ShoppingCardItemCount.Text = item.count.ToString();
                }
            };
```

But the problem is that this `productAddButton` is in a`ListView` Item and I need to update the item view in the list adapter. When I add `NotifyDataSetChanged` to the above code the while loop exits suddenly after the second run!

```
productAddButton.LongClick += async (s,e) =>
                {
                    while (productAddButton.Pressed)
                    {
                        item.count++;
                        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                        ShoppingCardItemCount.Text=item.count.ToString();
                        NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                };
```

I think it is because that the `ListView` recreates the item after it notified that data has been changed. So actually the button that i have been touching is gone and another button object was replaced with it. The whole item is actually replaced with another. So how can I handle this issue? Because I really need this feature in my app. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: can you update the ListView item "manually" and so avoid calling "notifyDatasetChanged()" until the user stops pressing the button?

Comment: @0X0nosugar How can I do that? I thought there isn't such a possibility in android ListView framework.

Comment: Surely you can edit the value of the text view, if you have a reference to it? Doing it as such should mean you won't have to refresh the list for the values to update.

Comment: I'm not sure about the xamarin part, that's why I'm not posting an answer, but from the android point of view, you have the button. So you can access its parent. That parent is your ListView item. So you can access all the children of this particular ListView item. Normally, that's a bad idea. But in your case, just call "notify..." as soon as the user stops pressing the button to clean things up

Comment: I tested it, But it does not change the value of the `TextView` before i call the `NotifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: thanks for letting me know -  I'll stop guessing in a minute, but I just ran into a [SO question/ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144400/find-parent-listviewitem-of-button-on-click-event) which indicates that the ListView item may not be the direct parent of the button. Maybe you'll find a way to access that TextView directly yet  -good luck :)

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception which drops you out of the loop ?